# How can the python interpreter read the charaset?

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm learning python. And i learned every comment starts with a hash "#". So how can the python interpreter read this line?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and set the charset to utf-8 ? (I'm using Python 2.7.3)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a comment. But this does not mean that python doesn't *see* it. So it can obviously parse it, too.

What python actually does is using the regular expression `coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)` on the first two lines. Most likely this is done even before the actual python parser steps in.

See [PEP-0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for details.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, can you explain this expression: `coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)`

Comment: Yes, it matches the string `coding` followed by either `:` or `=` followed by a random amount of whitespace followed by an alphanumeric string which may contain `-` and `.`, too. That string is matched as a group to be available without the `coding` etc. in front of it. http://www.debuggex.com/i/GFmypA0NPsJ9FgGU.png